# Highcharts map plugin scaling problems

Tags: javascript, svg, highcharts, highmaps

I've been investigating `highcharts` and `highmaps` in conjunction for a project I'm working on and have come up with a few problems.

The biggest one is the fact that when used as a plugin for `highcharts`, `highmaps` has some weird behavior.

First, it doesn't stop the display of the grid axes in a chart (similar to how pie and donut charts do). This however is solved with some creative color choices in their drawing.

But the biggest problems seem to come from the scaling it does when you try to zoom in (scroll) on the map.

Any ideas on how to fix the scrolling issue? Also disabling the axes would also be appreciated.

A jsfiddle with an example is here: http://jsfiddle.net/n8Lvn/

Comment: You mean you want to disable animation? http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts#chart.animation or something else?

Comment: No, no, no. When you try to 'navigate' the map, as they call it, instead of zooming in, the map gets unevenly stretched. I did notice that it doesn't happen that this doesn't happen to the same degree, depending on what mouse you have.

Comment: Zoom in or zoom out? Because when I zoom out it looks like wrong scaled.

Comment: For me it happens on the zoom in. But there is definitely a bug there.

Comment: Looks like a bug, I agree. Reported [here](https://github.com/highslide-software/highcharts.com/issues/3252). Thanks!